# Flex4 RichEditableText Height

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml, richtext

I noticed that the RichEditableText component has a default height and vertical content scrolling enabled by default.

My question is simple: What is the best way to make the RichEditableText component scale in height according to its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yourRichText.width = someExplicitWidth;`

Comment: I am concerned with the height property only, I'm attempting the opposite, to have the component scale its height according to the content inside it instead of having a static height.

Comment: a RichTextEditor is set to multiline and will change it's height dynamically if you set a width boundary.